# The request matched multiple endpoints,The error is reported when accessing the api is .net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: HTTP: GET /Api/MerchantApi/List HTTP: GET /Api/MerchantApi/List
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

```
[Api("Api/MerchantData/Page")]
public PageResult<MerchantDataList> Page(MerchantDataListInput input)
{
    var pageResult = Resolve<IMerchantDataService>().Page(input.BuildExpression(), input.PageIndex);
    var result = new List<MerchantDataList>();
    // 标签处理
    var tagIds = pageResult.Result.Select(r => r.Tags);
    var allTagRelation = Resolve<IRelationService>().Relations(tagIds);

    pageResult.Result.Foreach(entity =>
    {
        var item = entity.MapTo<MerchantDataList>();
        item.TagNames = allTagRelation.Where(r => entity.Tags.Contains(r.Id)).Select(r => r.Name).ToList();

        result.Add(item);
    });
    return ToPageResult(result, pageResult);
}

[Api("Api/MerchantData/List")]
public List<MerchantDataList> List(MerchantDataListInput input){
    var pageResult = Page(input);
    var result = pageResult.Result;
    return result;
}
```

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[HttpGet("Name")]`:

```
    //[Api("Api/MerchantData/Page")]
    [HttpGet("Api/MerchantData/Page")]
    public PageResult<MerchantDataList> Page(MerchantDataListInput input)
    {
        var pageResult = Resolve<IMerchantDataService>().Page(input.BuildExpression(), input.PageIndex);
        var result = new List<MerchantDataList>();
        // 标签处理
        var tagIds = pageResult.Result.Select(r => r.Tags);
        var allTagRelation = Resolve<IRelationService>().Relations(tagIds);

        pageResult.Result.Foreach(entity =>
        {
            var item = entity.MapTo<MerchantDataList>();
            item.TagNames = allTagRelation.Where(r => entity.Tags.Contains(r.Id)).Select(r => r.Name).ToList();

            result.Add(item);
        });
        return ToPageResult(result, pageResult);
    }

    //[Api("Api/MerchantData/List")]
    [HttpGet("Api/MerchantData/Page")]
    public List<MerchantDataList> List(MerchantDataListInput input){
        var pageResult = Page(input);
        var result = pageResult.Result;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can't use httpget, api is its own encapsulated interface